# RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'

Tags: python, python-asyncio

From all the research I've done, "There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'" error is thrown when code utilizes:

```
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

However, my code avoids this usage:

```
async def downloadAll(urls:dict, lastSet:bool, outfile):
    my_conn = TCPConnector(limit=20)
    async with ClientSession(connector=my_conn) as session:
        tasks = []
        for j, item in enumerate(urls):
            for id_, url in item.items():
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(downloadLink(url,id_,outfile,session))
                tasks.append(task)
        print("running async requests...")
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks,return_exceptions=True)
```

Yet this error is returned. I've read in the official Python docs to avoid altering attributes of async other than those at the top-level in cases of standard use, like this one.
Please advise, thank you.

Comment: How are you calling `downloadAll`? I don't think there's enough context here to answer what the problem is with certainty.

Comment: How did you get `loop`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.